# Does Adobe AIR need to be installed on an Android 2.2 Phone to run A Flex Mobile App?

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, air

Adobe AIR is pretty heavy. So is it necessary to be installed on my phone? Are there any alternatives to it..something lightweight.

Answer (score 3):

Start out by reading this pdf, it will give you all the information you need. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/developing_mobile_apps_flex.pdf

Short answer:

> If a user who doesn't have Adobe AIR
>   on his or her Android phone tries to
>   install Adobe AIR application he or
>   she will be presented a dialog asking
>   the user to install AIR and would be
>   taken to Android Market Place from
>   where the user can install AIR.

Another claim in this matter:

> Right now, there is no dependency
>   model for Android, thus users must
>   fulfill the dependencies of an
>   application manually.

Taken from this thread: http://www.quora.com/Do-Android-end-users-need-to-install-Adobe-AIR-manually-to-use-AIR-apps-on-the-platform

Comment: I got an error on my phone while installing telling "The Application Couldnt be installed" and I presumed it to be the lack of AIR.

Comment: To summarize, yes it will need to be installed, but the user will be prompted to install it when the app is first run if it's not there already.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you want to use Flex or Flash, you need Air.

Alternatives?

Well, you can use another cross-platform tool, like Phonegap.

But if you want small, lean apps, with maximum device compatibility, nothing compares with using Java and the stock Android SDK.

Edit:
P.S. "Heavy" is the word: requires ARMv7-A, FPU, Android 2.2
Many phones still being sold (as of 6/2011), such as LG Optimus V, do not meet these requirements.
http://www.adobe.com/products/air/systemreqs/

You may find these links useful
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/android.html

See also Plastic Sturgeon's comment here: [Choosing flash/openGL/other animation for an android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203086/choosing-flash-opengl-other-animation-for-an-android-app/6203416#6203416)